is there any way to use a proxy for Anthropic Computer Use Demo?
I was wondering if there's a way to send the requests of Anthropic Computer Use Demo
(https://github.com/anthropics/anthropic-quickstarts/tree/main/computer-use-demo#accessing-the-demo-app) to a local API server.
I've tested both ollama and LM Studio redirecting the requests through Apache2 proxy, but the results are 404 not found endpoint for the docker requests.
I suppose Claude API server use a quite protected connection to not broadcast the routes the app navigate.
Any clue would be much appreciated.
